# What is a good practice for redirecting a xhr or fetch request to a new page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch

I wonder if there is any standard/best practice how to handle the following scenario:

> The browser does an xhr of fetch request, and the response should indicate that the browser should navigate to a new location.

An examples could be that the users sends a chat message, the browsers send a fetch request, and the response is that the user is not logged in, and that the browser should navigate to the login page.

Now, you could just a 3xx response, and with fetch this can be handled like this:

```
const response = await fetch(request);

if (response.redirected) {
  window.location.href = response.url;
}
```

However, this will cause the redirected page to be loaded 2 times. Which is very ugly, and even worse, if the redirected page is an external page it will throw.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't something you should generally expect to handle on your client. Instead, your server should not redirect JSON requests to HTML pages.

On your server, if a request asks for JSON, you should respond with a `401 Unauthorized` and a JSON document containing error information.

The same request for HTML should redirect to the login page.

Most server-side frameworks have a way of telling which format a given request is asking for, and of issuing the correct response type.

Comment: What if I want to redirect another page on success? For example, when the payment plan is executed successfully, I want to redirect to the order history. I guess respond with 200 with a new location in the body or the header of the response?

Comment: @Kasper You shouldn't design APIs this way. Your API needs to output HTML and HTTP Redirects in response to HTML requests only, and it should not output HTML or redirect to pages that output HTML in response to XHR or JSON requests. If you want to perform an XHR and then "redirect" to a new page, your client should expect a 200 or 201 response and a JSON payload indicating success and possibly where to redirect the user, and then redirect via `window.location.href`.

Comment: Ah, yes, that is exactly what I meant to say. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, that's one option. Another option would be to decouple the logic server side, so the API knows how to create a record, but makes no assumptions about where the client will want to be redirected to. Your client can perform the API call and then it should know how to render the results, whether that is inserting the resulting record into a list that is already being displayed, or loading a new route. Typically APIs return information about the created record, they don't tell the client what to do with that information.

Comment: I see thanks. Well there is a lot of legacy here, and the backend wants to be "in charge". Would you put the new location then in the header "Location", or in the json responnse body?

Comment: In the response body.